# How to display array as a prop in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-props

I am taking product object with API call and there is an array named 'variations'. I want to show the 'name' of this array inside of the dropdown component. here is my dropdown component:

```
<template>
    <div v-bind:class="{row: rowStyle, 'form-group': !smallSize}">
        <label v-if="label" v-bind:class="labelClass">{{ label }}</label>
        <div class="input-group" v-bind:class="controlColumnAmount">
            <!--       Optimize the onchange event so it returns the selected object instead of the value (selected id) -->
            <select
                v-on:change="$emit('value', getReturnValue($event.target.value))"
                :placeholder="placeholder"
                :disabled="disabled"
                :id="selectBoxName"
                class="form-control"
                v-bind:class="selectClasses" >
                <option disabled selected v-if="defaultValue != '' && defaultSelected == undefined">{{ defaultValue }}</option>
                <option v-for="option in options" :value="getKeyValue(option)[0]" :selected="option == defaultSelected">
                    {{ getKeyValue(option)[1] }}
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import {v4 as uuidv4} from 'uuid';
import GENERAL_COMPONENT_CONSTANTS from "../constants/GeneralComponentConstants";

export default {
    props: {
        id: { type: String, default: "" },
        label: { type: String, default: "" },
        options: { type: Array, default: () => [] },
        optionsKey: { type: [String, Array], default: undefined },
        returnObject: { type: Boolean, default: true },
        componentStyle: { type: String, default: GENERAL_COMPONENT_CONSTANTS.componentStyle.Row },
        labelColumns: { type: Number, default: 4 },
        disabled: { type: Boolean, default: false },
        placeholder: {type: String, default: ""},
        defaultValue: { type: String, default: "-- Select an option --" },
        defaultSelected: { type: [String, Object], default: undefined},
        fetchOptions: { type: String, default: undefined },
        smallSize: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    },

    watch: {
        options: function () {
            document.getElementById(this.selectBoxName).selectedIndex = 0;
        }
    },

    data() {
        return {
            selectBoxName: "select-" + uuidv4(),
        }
    },

    methods: {
        getKeyValue: function(option) {
            if(option.hasOwnProperty("value")) {
                return [option.id, option.value];
            } else if(this.optionsKey instanceof Array) {
                let label = "";
                this.optionsKey.forEach((key) => {
                    label += (this.getNestedValue(key, option) + " ");
                });
                return [option.id, label];
            } else {
                return [option.id, this.getNestedValue(this.optionsKey, option)];
            }
        },
        getReturnValue: function(selectedValue) {
            if (!this.returnObject) {
                return selectedValue;
            } else {
                return this.options.find((option) => {
                    return option.id == selectedValue;
                })
            }
        },
        isOptionArray: function () {
            return (this.options.length > 0 && this.options[0].hasOwnProperty("value"))
        },
        getNestedValue(keyPath, object){
            let keyPathArray = keyPath.split(".");
            if (keyPathArray.length <= 1) {
                return object[keyPathArray[0]];
            } else {
                let extractedObject = object[keyPathArray.shift()];
                return this.getNestedValue(keyPathArray.join("."), extractedObject);
            }
        },
    },

    computed: {
        rowStyle: function() {
            return this.componentStyle == GENERAL_COMPONENT_CONSTANTS.componentStyle.Row;
        },
        labelColumnAmount: function () {
            return "col-sm-" + this.labelColumns;
        },
        labelClass: function() {
            let labelClass = "";
            if (this.rowStyle) {
                labelClass += 'col-form-label ';
                labelClass += this.labelColumnAmount;
            }
            return labelClass;
        },
        controlColumnAmount: function () {
            if (!this.rowStyle) {
                return '';
            } else if (this.label) {
                return "col-sm-" + (12 - this.labelColumns);
            } else {
                return "col-sm-12";
            }
        },
        selectClasses() {
            return {
                'form-control-sm': this.smallSize,
            };
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

And with this component, I want to show the name of the variations. So in the example below, I want to show Child and Adult as vartiation.name inside of the dropdown.

[image]

"product" is the product of the object.

```
   <h2>{{ product.attributes.name }}</h2>
                            <Dropdown
                                class="select"
                            />
```

So what can I do in the dropdown to show the variation.name in dropdown.

Comment: You can try `<Dropdown :options="product.attributes.variations.map(item => [item.id, item.name])" />`

Comment: I am getting an error like this: vue.esm.js:1897 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split'), I just edited my code to make my component clear. Could you have a look?

Comment: I can't debug the code for you - but it seems that somewhere in your code there is a `.split(` and the thing on the left of the dot is null/undefined. You should investigate why it is undefined.